# NativeScript Playground - Built-in classes not applied

Tags: css, vue.js, nativescript

I'm new to NativeScript. I'm using it right now through the Playground service
I discovered some built-in classes that apply some styling, such as: `btn-primary`
Though when using it, the button's style doesn't change on my Android device
However, some other classes *do* apply, e.g. `h1`-`h6`, which confuses me a lot

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: You are suppose to use `btn-primary` along with `btn` (`btn btn-primary`), if still doesn't work please share a Playground example.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=qn28jy&v=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `btn-primary` you should include [compat CSS files](https://github.com/NativeScript/theme#theme-classes-and-compatibility).

```
@import '~@nativescript/theme/css/core.compat.css';
@import '~@nativescript/theme/css/default.compat.css';
```

Using `btn-primary` is old way of styling elements. With new version just adding `-primary` as class should do the job instead of `btn btn-primary`.

Examples for using new version can be found in [Github](https://github.com/NativeScript/theme/tree/master/app) if you wish to understand new way of styling elements.

Comment: The `-primary` solved my problem, and the GitHub link will be useful. Thanks!